# How to create a command line to run c# exe file and give some parameters to a function in form1?

Tags: c#, cmd, command-line, parameters, exe

I have c# program that I want to run but from the cmd using a command line so here is my question I don't know how to create the command and I don't know how to send the parameter in my command to some function there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Process class to execute files.

```
var fileName = "some.exe";
var arguments = "";
var info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(fileName, arguments);
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;

// if you want read output
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process { StartInfo = info };

process.Start();
var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
var error =  process.StandardError?.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! However I am new to this so I still don't know how I will write the command in the cmd and also the arguments should be entered by the user from the cmd not from the code, and this arguments should be sent to some function in form 1 so can you help me with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if your application is console you can use agrs,static void Main(string[] args).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a console application and after generating (by building) `.exe` file, you can call with the arguments in command line.

Sample Example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
        var b = Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);
        Console.WriteLine(a+b);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

[image]